# Android Studio: app merge release resource FAILD

Tags: java, android-studio, build

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ImageButton button1;
    ImageButton button2;
    ImageButton button3;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
public void addListenerOnButton(){
    button1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, ForthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}
`I'm stuck with building an apk, using Android Studio. Messages Gradle Build always shows ":app:mergeReleaseResource FAILD". I wonder if there are something wrong with .png file.[The picture shows the details in Messages Gradle Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Bam.png)

Comment: Is it was a .png file at first or you have renamed it to .png?

Comment: I renamed it. And I forget what type it first was.

Comment: I also renamed other pictures, but they don't have the problem.

Comment: first `Build > Rebuild Project`.otherwise post your app's `build.gradle` for more details.